# Update with one row which doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below and I want to update the values in the table, but also insert one or 2 rows.

So update rows 1 - 7 with changed values and add one row for a new value.

Table

```
ID (Auto increment)        -   ID_advertentie      -     VALUE
1                                  12                     tst1
2                                  12                     tst2
3                                  12                     tst3
4                                  12                     tst4
5                                  12                     tst5
6                                  12                     tst6
7                                  12                     tst7
```

Comment: just a though, is it mandatory that updation done before the insertion or it could be second. if it is second operation you can fetch the last inserted id and after that run a query to update else based on your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax. So you'd have your insert query, and then have it update existing rows with that syntax.

Alternatively, if that doesn't work for you, just do two separate queries.